# Probability that a game show contetstent picks a red ball from box 1

Tags: probability, conditional-probability

> A game involves picking coloured balls from two boxes, referred to as
>   Box 1 and Box 2. **Box 1 contains two red balls and seven green balls**.
>   **Box 2 contains four green balls and three red balls**. The balls are
>   identical in every respect except for their colour. A blindfolded
>   player first chooses a box and then picks a ball. **If a certain player
>   picks a red ball, what is the probability that the player chose from
>   Box 1?**

The formula I have used to solve this is Bayes Theron
[image]

Plugging in the numbers asked in the question

[image]

`= .2/` or 20%

Is this the correct answer also did I use the formula correctly?

Comment: I have no idea where your calculation is coming from.  What are your events $A,B$?  Are you really claiming that $P(A\cap B)=50\times 2$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$p(1\text{ and }R)=\frac{1}{2}\cdot\frac{2}{9}=\frac{1}{9}$. $p(2\text{ and }R)=\frac{1}{2}\cdot\frac{3}{7}=\frac{3}{14}$. Hence $$p(1|R)=\frac{\frac{1}{9}}{\frac{1}{9}+\frac{3}{14}}=\frac{14}{41}$$

Answer (score 0):

Let $R$ be the probability he picks a red ball, $I$ for box 1, $II$ for box 2.

So by the law of total probability $$P(R) = P(R|I)P(I) + P(R|II)P(II) = \frac{2}{9}\frac12 + \frac37\frac12 = \frac{7}{63} + \frac{27}{126}= \frac{41}{126}$$

and 
$$P(R \cap I)=P(R|I)P(I) = \frac12\cdot \frac29=\frac{2}{18} = \frac{14}{126}$$

so that $$P(I | R)=\frac{P(I \cap R)}{P(R)} = \frac{14}{41} $$